# Find Index of current route then pass index to component props using React JS and React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have following the scenario where I have a few post links that route to a single page they belong to. Problem is, I am using the same component in the single page to display the photo but can't figure out how to pass the current index index so only the current indexed photo shows up. I am using react router and retrieving my data through an api call.

Single.js:

```
 export default class single extends React.Component {

 constructor() {
   super();
 }

static propTypes = {
  posts: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
 };

 render() {
  const { postId } = this.props.params;
  const i = this.props.posts.findIndex((post) => post._id === postId);
  const post = this.props.posts[i];

  return (
    <section className="blog-landing-page">  
      <Photo {...this.props} key={i} i={i} post={post} />
   </section>
     );
  }
}
```

Photo.js

```
  export default class posts extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
     super();
   }
   render() {
     const { post, i} = this.props;
      return (
        <section>
         <Link to={`/post/${post.key}`}>
             <img src={post.image.url} alt='' className="grid-photo" />
         <h1>{post.name}</h1>
         </Link>
       </section>
      );
    }
   }
```

When console logging inside "single.js" I get the following output attached.

```
         console.log(this.props.posts)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you logged `this.props.post` in `photo.js`?

Comment: Which router do you use?

Answer (score 0):

On your Route component you can access datas as [params](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params)  and then pass it down to the child.

```
class SomeRoute extends Component {
    render () {
      <Child photoId = {this.props.params.photoId} />
    }
}
```

You just need to be sure to name the route param

```
<Route path="/foo/:photoId/bar" component={SomeRoute }/>
```

Comment: My current setup already, but doesnt work: <Route path='/blog' component={BlogLandingPage} />
      <Route path='/post/:postId' component={Single}  />
  </Route>

Comment: On Single is it acessing this.props.params.postId? Can you log this.props.params to be sure?

Comment: It outputs out fine but now im getting a new error. "Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `children` was not specified in `App`."  
        <Photo {...this.props} photoId = {postId} />

Comment: App component needs children and you are probably rendering it as <App /> if this component is yours and you want it to optionally not have children check the propTypes on it and remove the .isRequired part

Comment: Removed that now getting this error: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined

Comment: Check the line you are acessing something like foo.key and foo is undefined

Comment: Maybe since I am using as a link in photo.js then using the same component in the single? Inside photo.js I have <Link to={`/post/${post.key}`}>